# Linq to Lambda Conversion using LinqPad

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, linqpad

I am new to Linq and Lambda. Today itself i stepped into it. I have experience with Sql. So after going through this forum came across LinqPad and somehow managed to write my Sql query in Linq. When i write this Linq code in Visual Studio it's working fine without any errors. But the requirement is i need to write it in Lambda. So i tried to use LinqPad to convert it but its giving our below errors

**Working Linq Code in VS**

```
public async Task<int> GetTotalStudentsAsync(int deanId, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var result = from userBarSession in _unitOfWork.Read<UserBarSession>()
                    join deansStudent in _unitOfWork.Read<DeansStudent>() on userBarSession.Id equals deansStudent.UserBarSessionId
                    where deansStudent.DeanId == deanId && userBarSession.StartDate == fromDate && userBarSession.EndDate == toDate
                    select new
                    {
                        UserID = userBarSession.UserId

                    };
        return result.ToList().Count();
    }
```

**Error in LinqPad**

[image: **Error in LinqPad**]

"deanId" in red is showing the error as "The name deanId doesn't exist in the current context"

"UserBarSessionId" in red is showing the error as "**DeansStudents** Doesn't contain a definition for **UserBarSessionId** and no extension method **UserBarSessionId** is accepting a first argument of type 'DeansStudents' could be found"

```
public class DeansStudent 
{
  [Key] 
  public int DeanId { get; set; } 

  [Key] 
  public int UserBarSessionId { get; set; } 

  public virtual User User { get; set; } 

  public virtual UserBarSession UserBarSession { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Post snapshot of `DeansStudents` class and  piece of code where `deanId` is declared

Comment: `public class DeansStudent
    {
        [Key]
        public int DeanId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int UserBarSessionId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual UserBarSession UserBarSession { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @Sumitraj deanId is declared as parameters

Comment: If you are letting LinqPad build the data context itself, you should check what fields  it has created and how they are spelt.

Answer (score 1):

The `deanId` needs to be declared in LINQpad, either as parameter to method within LINQpad or as variable just before. Your LINQpad probably wouldn't find `fromDate` or `toDate` if that was part of your expression there.

```
int deanId = 1;
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;
var result = from userBarSession in UserBarSession
             join deansStudent in DeanStudents on userBarSession.Id equals deansStudent.UserBarSessionId
             where deansStudent.DeanId == deanId && userBarSession.StartDate == fromDate && userBarSession.EndDate == toDate
             select new
             {
                 UserID = userBarSession.UserId
             };
```

Comment: Sorry. fromDate and toDate is not in my current expression. As you mentioned I declared UserId and that error is gone. but the first one near "UserBarSessionId" is still there. It gives out following error. 

"DeansStudents' does not contain a definition for 'UserBarSessionId' and no extension method 'UserBarSessionId' accepting a first argument of type 'DeansStudents' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Comment: @Vasalath Is it possible that you have one class named `DeanStudent` and another one named `DeanStudents` where `UserBarSessionId` is defined in the first one only? In your examples, the VS code uses `DeanStudent` while the linqpad query uses `DeanStudents`.